# Having trouble understanding when to use int or string in Coredata

Tags: ios, swift, string, core-data, int

iOS 10, Swift3

I am making an application where user fetches their daily agenda from server, and I wanna save their schedule in Coredata. A simple json from API comes like

```
{
                "id": 11639002,
                "subject": "Coffeee",
                "startUTC": "2017-05-03T15:00:00+00:00",
                "endUTC": "2017-05-03T16:00:00+00:00"
}
```

If a change is made on server side I wanna update the appointment also I dont wanna save duplicate entries. Also I wanna be able to sort this row by `startDate` I wanna pass around this appointment row by its `id`

I thought a good solution for this would be like this

```
@NSManaged public var id: Int32
@NSManaged public var subject: String?
@NSManaged public var startUTC: NSDate?
@NSManaged public var endUTC: NSDate?
```

Every single post I read here says that Coredata is not ORM or relational database , so developer should get away from that mind state.

I dont understand how and why would I need to get away from relational database mindset when I am trying to replicate unique_id approach like in server side.

This tutorial http://dorianroy.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-implement-unique-constraints-in-core-data-with-ios-9/

says that

> No more fetch/if/else
>
> Until now, when you wanted to import data objects into Core Data from
>   a file or network request, you had to create a fetch request for each
>   incoming object with a predicate that matches the id and then execute
>   it to look for an existing version of that object. If you found one,
>   you would update it, otherwise create a new object. With Unique
>   Constraints, you don’t have to do this fetch/if/else anymore and save
>   lots of DB requests while parsing the data.

and `Unique Constraints must be strings`

So all I want to do is to not have duplicate rows and update the row by it's id.

What approach should I use? Do I have to make `id`s string like in that blog post or old regular 32 bit integer approach would work too?

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is you should write code you understand and in a way that others seeing it for the first time can understand. 
It's true that core data isn't a relational database, and yet it's a wrapper around one. So if it you can solve your problems using that paradigm, it is simple and understandable, I say go for it.  Be prepared to revisit your implementation somewhere down the road. But you'll understand your issues  better by then.